# Where did the original Tros of Samothrace novellas end in comparison with the novel?

Tags: talbot-mundy

I'm reading Talbot Mundy's *[Tros of Samothrace](http://freeread.com.au/@RGLibrary/TalbotMundy/Novels/@Novels.html)*. I understand it was first published in [Adventure magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_(magazine)) in 1925-26 as [several novellas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tros_of_Samothrace).

I'm curious about how it divides, especially **which chapters mark the end of the various novellas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tros_of_Samothrace#Publishing_history):

> The original sequence of novellas appeared as follows:
>   
> 1. "Tros of Samothrace", 10 February 1925 (later became chapters 1–14 of the novel)
>   2. "The Enemy of Rome", 10 April 1925 (chapters 15–26)
>   3. "Prisoners of War", 10 June 1925 (chapters 27–37)
>   4. "Hostages to Luck", 20 August 1925 (chapters 38–51)
>   5. "Admiral of Caesar's Fleet", 10 October 1925 (chapters 52–66)
>   6. "The Dancing Girl of Gades", 10 December 1925 (chapters 67–81)
>   7. "Messenger of Destiny", part 1, 10 February 1926 (chapters 82–87)
>   8. "Messenger of Destiny", part 2, 20 February 1926 (chapters 88–92)
>   9. "Messenger of Destiny", part 3, 28 February 1926 (chapters 93–96)
>   
> When *Tros of Samothrace* was published in four paperback volumes in 1967 and 1971, the breaks between volumes coincided with Mundy's own breaks between episodes:
>   
> *Tros* contains "Tros of Samothrace" and "The Enemy of Rome"
>   *Helma* contains "Prisoners of War" and "Hostages to Luck"
>   *Liafail* contains "Admiral of Caesar's Fleet" and "The Dancing Girl of Gades"
>   *Helene* contains all three parts of "Messenger of Destiny"
>   
> When *Tros of Samothrace* was reissued in three paperback volumes in 1976, the breaks between volumes came partway through "Prisoners of War" and "Admiral of Caesar's Fleet".

Answer (score 1):

Tros of Samothrace was published in five books as follows: Tros (26 chapters), Helma (25 chapters), Liafail (30 chapters), Helene (15 chapters), Queen Cleopatra (42 chapters), and Purple Pirate (47 chapters).